# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I have seen this error before and it was due to something quite unrelated, but I can't seem to get past this now try as I might. The whole error seems contradictory to me, but Python is probably somehow right in the end.

So, in foo/foo.py I have a class and its constructor defined as below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bars):
        self.bars = bars
```

In baz.py I have the following:

```
from foo import foo
test_bars = [ a list of things ]
f = foo.Foo(test_bars)
```

which leads me to

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I tried turning the constructor into kwargs too, as below

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bars=None):
        self.bars = bars
```

and then calling

```
from foo import foo
test_bars = [ a list of things ]
f = foo.Foo(bars=test_bars)
```

and this gives an error about unidentified kwarg.

Other classes included in foo/foo.py seem to work normally.

What is it I'm not seeing?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're importing the file you think you are.  Try ``from foo import foo; print foo.__file__`` to see exactly where it's coming from.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the file is right: <project_folder>\foo\foo.py

And it gives a different error msg if I touch the constructor arguments. It must be something else.

Comment: Perhaps you have two ``class Foo``s in the file?  That's not an error, and any changes you make to the first one will have no effect.

Comment: Oh yeah, you guessed right. Sorry, saw your comment after I'd posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Duhh, I knew it had to be something stupid. I had an older implementation of the class with the same name defined below everything. I only saw it when I scrolled down enough.

Answer (score 0):

1) importing wrong class foo its Foo i.e from foo import Foo.

2) foo.Foo should be only Foo

```
from foo import Foo
test_bars = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
f = Foo(test_bars)
```

Comment: Actually, foo.Foo is much clearer and also recommended by [Python style guides](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/)

Comment: he is only importing the class Foo, not the whole module foo. So, if u try to run foo.Foo() it will generate an error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "baz.py", line 3, in <module>
    f = foo.Foo(test_bars)
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined